# how to filter swiftyjson array

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I'll try every solution which I get from stack overflow but its my bad luck. I store my JSON response in [Any] array like this:

```
var json = JSON()
var arrClientType = [Any]()

self.json = JSON(value) //value is json data
self.arrClientType = self.json["client_type_data"].arrayValue
```

now, I want to filter this array and reload that filtered data in tableview.

```
[{
  "client_type_name" : "Asset Manager",
  "client_type_id" : 1
}, {
  "client_type_name" : "Broker Dealer",
  "client_type_id" : 5
}, {
  "client_type_name" : "Corporate",
  "client_type_id" : 8
}, {
  "client_type_name" : "Custodian and Prime Broker",
  "client_type_id" : 3
}, {
  "client_type_name" : "Diversified Financial Services Firms",
  "client_type_id" : 4
}, {
  "client_type_name" : "Fund Administrator",
  "client_type_id" : 6
}, {
  "client_type_name" : "Hedge Fund Manager",
  "client_type_id" : 2
}, {
  "client_type_name" : "Individual",
  "client_type_id" : 7
}]
```

I'll try this also :

```
 let filtered = JSON(self.arrList).arrayValue.filter({
                    $0["client_type_name"].arrayValue.map({ $0.stringValue }).contains("Broker Dealer")
                })
                print ("filterdData: \(filtered)")
```

but it give me entry filter array.

Please help me.

Comment: FYI - there is no point to SwiftJSON or other 3rd party JSON libraries. Use the new Swift 4 Codable or using JSONSerialization.

Comment: **Never** use `Any` if the type is clearly more specific. You are fighting the strong type system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
     filtered = arrList.filter { $0["client_type_name"].stringValue.contains("Broker Dealer")  }
```

and change your self.arrlist to array of dictiony type

```
 var arrList: [JSON]  = []
 var filtered :[JSON] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one , you will be able to filtered the data which **contain** the **"client_type_name"** as a **Broker Dealer**.

```
let arrClientType = [["client_type_name":"Asset Manager" , "client_type_id":1] , ["client_type_name":"Broker Dealer" , "client_type_id":5] , ["client_type_name":"Corporate" , "client_type_id":8]]


if let filteredData = arrClientType.filter({(($0 as? [String:Any])?["client_type_name"] as? String ?? "") == "Broker Dealer"}) as? [Any] {

            print(filteredData)

        }
```

The filteredData is the arrayOfDictionary which contain the dictionaries in which **"client_type_name"** as a **Broker Dealer**.